# Reflect a list value into another list?

Tags: java, reflection

```
List <ClassA> listA; List <ClassB> listB;
```

Can I use reflection to reflect listA into listB? I got below code but only reflect an object

```
public static <A, B> B convert(A instance,
                               Class<B> targetClass) throws Exception {
    B target = (B)targetClass.newInstance();

    for (Field targetField : targetClass.getDeclaredFields()) {
        targetField.setAccessible(true);
        Field field =
            instance.getClass().getDeclaredField(targetField.getName());
        field.setAccessible(true);
        targetField.set(target, field.get(instance));
    }
    return target;
}
```

Comment: Don't do this. What you're doing here is extremely strange. If these two types have common operations, make them implement a common interface.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general the `convert` method is not likely to work (for `List`s or any other type).

Calling `Field.setAccessible(true)` allows read and write access to private fields but will not allow modification of `final` fields via `Field.set()` (an `IllegalAccessException: Field is final` exception is thrown).

Depending on the implementation of `List` you are trying to copy this may prevent it from working correctly. For example, using `ArrayList` such as:

```
// Note that this is an unchecked cast
List<ClassB> listB = (List<ClassB>) convert(listA, ArrayList.class);
```

fails when trying to copy `serialVersionUID`.

The following change to the posted code gets round this problem for `static final serialVersionUID` in `ArrayList`:

```
public static <A, B> B convert(A instance, 
                           Class<B> targetClass) throws Exception { 
    B target = (B)targetClass.newInstance(); 

    for (Field targetField : targetClass.getDeclaredFields()) { 
        targetField.setAccessible(true); 
        Field field = 
            instance.getClass().getDeclaredField(targetField.getName()); 
        field.setAccessible(true); 

        // Ignore attempts to set final fields
        try {
            targetField.set(target, field.get(instance)); 
        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
            continue;
        }
    } 

    return target; 
}
```

However, the next problem is that the `convert` method is performing a shallow copy. For `List`s of different types this altered version of `convert` may appear to work correctly but it does not convert the `ClassA` objects in the list to `ClassB` (the unchecked cast above hides this). This will likely cause `ClassCastException`s to be thrown later in the application.

Fixing this problem can be achieved by adding another method to wrap `convert`:

```
public static <A, B extends List<C>, C> B convertList(
    List<A> list, Class<B> targetListClass, Class<C> targetClass) 
    throws Exception {

    B targetList = targetListClass.newInstance();

    for (A object : list) {
        targetList.add(convert(object, targetClass));
    }

    return targetList;
}
```

This will then need to be called as:

```
List<ClassB> listB = (List<ClassB>) convertList(
    listA, ArrayList.class, ClassB.class);
```

Comment: Hi Matthew Murdoch can you explain to me why will cause fails when trying to copy serialVersionUID when reflect the list and one object to object wont get this error. And what you mean by shallow copy? Thanks you veyr much

Answer (score 1):

Try it.

But it is not needed. You can just add the contents of the first list to the second one:

```
List list2 = new ArrayList(list1);
```

As it seems, your two `List`s are declared with different generic types. So you will have to use unsafe casts. But it feels horribly wrong to do this. What are you actually trying to achieve? If the types of objects in the lists are supposed to be different, then why are you trying to copy them?

Comment: Sorry i didn't notive my <ClassA> <ClassB> doesn't show out. Basically is two List that take in different class type of object

Comment: actually this two Class have same attributes, for some reason must convert the ClassB into ClassA

Comment: then use the exampel I gave you. If the compiler complains, use casts

Comment: Ya this method I tried before already, beside using this is it possible to use reflection?

Comment: you need not do it with reflection. You can, if you want. Check your other question for details.

Answer (score 0):

Technically spoken, yes, but only under certain conditions. Assume, you want to convert a ClassA instance into a ClassB instance. The line of code to start the conversion would be like:

```
ClassB bInstance = convert(aInstance, ClassB.class);
```

Am I correct so far?

The above code will (1) create a new ClassB object, using it's default constructor, (2) get all fields declared on ClassB (but **no** fields from any ClassB supertype!), (3) get the same field from ClassA and (4) set the value from aInstance to the field in the newly created ClassB instance.

So far so good.

But this will only work if and only if ClassA has exact the same fields as ClassB at minimum (it may have more fields). That's the limitation. If ClassA and ClassB do not fulfill this precondition, you'll have to catch the exceptions and handle those cases separately, like:

```
    try {
    Field field =
        instance.getClass().getDeclaredField(targetField.getName());
        field.setAccessible(true);
        try {
          targetField.set(target, field.get(instance));
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
          handleIncompatibleType(target, targetField, field.get(instance));
        }
    } catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {
        handleMissingFieldInA(instance, targetField);
    }
```

Same fields means: same field name and same field type (or at least a 'castable' type)

So if you have a `List<ClassA>` but need a `List<ClassB>`, you could iterate through the first list, convert the List items into ClassB objects and write them to the target list.